# Build list of typeclass instances for HList type

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to improve types for one of our APIs. I want to create data fetcher with following signature:

```scala
def runIt[T <: HList](id: Int): T = ???
```

It should fetch call external server for some entity and return HList with required data. The first task is to build list of API params for required features.

Here it what I made:

```scala
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

trait Feature

trait FeatureFetcher[T] {
  def name: String
}

trait F1 extends Feature
trait F2 extends Feature

implicit case object f1Fetcher extends FeatureFetcher[F1] {
  val name = "f1name"
}

implicit case object f2Fetcher extends FeatureFetcher[F2] {
  val name = "f2name"
}

def makeIt[T <: HList](id: Int)
                      (implicit liftAll: LiftAll[FeatureFetcher, T]) = {

  // I need this, but it does not compile here
  // liftAll.instances.toList.map(_.name).mkString(",")

  liftAll.instances
}

makeIt[F1 :: F2 :: HNil](1).toList.map(_.name).mkString(",")
```

It actually works. But when I move `.toList` into `makeIt` function I get error

```
Error:(25, 21) could not find implicit value for parameter toTraversableAux: shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable.Aux[liftAll.Out,List,Lub]
liftAll.instances.toList.map(_.name).mkString(",")
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [segeljakt](https://gitter.im/milessabin/shapeless?at=5adca5f901a2b40f382ef8cd), try passing `liftAll.Out` to `ToTraversable.Aux` via `LiftAll.Aux` like so

```
def makeIt[In <: HList, Out <: HList](id: Int)(implicit
  liftAll: LiftAll.Aux[FeatureFetcher, In, Out],
  toTraversable: ToTraversable.Aux[Out, List, FeatureFetcher[_]]
): String = {
  liftAll.instances.toList.map(_.name).mkString(",")
}

type In = F1 :: F2 :: HNil
type Out = FeatureFetcher[F1] :: FeatureFetcher[F2] :: HNil
makeIt[In, Out](1)
// res1: String = f1name,f2name
```

or based on [`ToElmTypes`](https://github.com/reactormonk/scala-elm-types/blob/d15abf57421d18a2c288c8ad575bfe5e340a2c17/core/src/main/scala/elmtype/ElmTypeMain.scala#L21)

```
case class MakeIt[In <: HList]() {
  def apply[Out <: HList](id: Int)(implicit
    liftAll: LiftAll.Aux[FeatureFetcher, In, Out],
    toTraversable: ToTraversable.Aux[Out, List, FeatureFetcher[_]]
  ): String = {
    liftAll.instances.toList.map(_.name).mkString(",")
  }
}

MakeIt[F1 :: F2 :: HNil].apply(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when the code calls implicit instance with `implicit liftAll: LiftAll[FeatureFetcher, T]` then the dependent type Out of LiftAll is lost, so the compiler doesn't know which type of instances exactly will return and hence the error.

A possible solution could be to use, use its `the` from `shapeless` which is supposed to be a better implicitly.

```
the[liftAll].instances.toList
```

Let me know if ut helps!!